# Typing indicator for MSBOT framework in node.js only shows up once

Tags: node.js, botframework, ibm-watson

so I'm currently building a bot using IBM Watson Assistant. When I send a message, I usually want it to show a typing indicator bubble animation every time the user sends a message. Every time the user sends a message and the bot receives it, the function "session.sendTyping()" gets called, so I expect it to show every time the user sends a button. However, the typing indicator animation only shows up for the first message the user sends and disappears for the rest of the session. I tried to do some deep searching as to why that's happening, and I decided to log the batches being sent. Usually, one batch has the type "typing", and another has the type "message". In the first message, they send separately. However, for all the other messages, they sent together which may be the reason why I don't see the typing indicator.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why this is happening, or why this is the case?